# Can WebASM provide JavaScript style interactivity without the same vulnerabilities?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, exploit, tor, web-assembly

JavaScript is useful for interactivity. However, it is often disabled by security conscious browsers, such as the Tor Browser Bundle, and blocked with plugins such as NoScript.

I was wondering if it was possible for WebASM to provide JavaScript style interactivity on a webpage?

I was also curious whether WebASM might allow page interactivity, whilst safeguarding against browser exploitation, such as the attack against Freedom Mail in 2013 where the FBI used a JavaScript exploit.

*I am well aware, that in the TorMail example above, the only users that got impacted were those that forgot to disable JavaScript.*

*WebASM introducing new (different) vulnerabilities is outside the scope of the question. This question should mostly focus on comparing against JS.*

Comment: It's like saying "I know driving a car around can end on a fatal accident, so instead of car I will use a boat."

Comment: @ThoriumBR No, it's like saying "I am sick and tired of websites on the DarkNet looking like they are from 1990, and I would like some JavaScript interactivity without risking my user's security and privacy"

Comment: Javascript compromises privacy because it let the website run code on the client side. WebASM let the website run code on the client side.

Comment: not without some regular javascript, which you need to load and setup the ASM. there's also no easy (as in html/css/js) way of programming such page interactivity. Given how battle-tested and mature JS and the BOM is nowadays and how fresh ASM is, I would expect JS to actually be safer.

Comment: @ThoriumBR True. I just wondered if perhaps it was safer, took a different approach etc...

Comment: I would say it's safer to use an older, more mature and more attacked platform than a newer one. Different approaches work when everything works, the bugs are what get you. And WebASM is newer, so it will have more unknown and undiscovered bugs.